# A distribution similar to the Poisson one?

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-regression

[image: Histogram of my data]

I have a set of data which in my opinion can be treated as coming from a Poisson distribution (they are all positive and represent days). I need to perform several regressions, with R, using these data as dependent variables. I tried linear models (manipulating the data using the Box-Cox transformation) and `glm` with all possible families but when I check if the residuals are normally distributed (using Shapiro's test) the answer is always negative. Any idea about any other possible distribution family? Thanks!

Comment: Is normality assumption on deviance residuals  required in poisson regression?

Comment: For a start, don't expect Pearson or deviance residuals from a generalized linear model to be normally distributed.

Comment: The right type of regression depends on the *dependent* variable, not the independent ones. Please clarify what your model is, including DV, IVs, research question etc.

Comment: Why do you think that you would need the residuals to be normal?

Comment: They are not intervals but just numbers which can be treated as counts. I thought that the residuals were supposed to be normal but reading your comments I guess I was wrong!

Comment: I'm concerned about the expression 'numbers which can be treated as counts'. Some numbers that we might be tempted to regard as counts, or as count-like, do not really behave like true count data.

Answer (score 5):

(got too long for a comment; hopefully it will become a more complete answer if you respond to some of these issues)

**Most important**:

when you say 'number of days' are you looking at intervals of *time*?

Intervals of time, such as a count of days between some start event and some end event *won't be Poisson*.

Poisson is for counts of (independent) *events*, not counts of the number of time intervals that have gone by between them. You might consider exponential or gamma GLMs for those.

**Secondly**:

Why do you think that you would need the residuals from a GLM to be normal?

--

A potential answer: If your data are truly count data*, then you might consider the negative binomial.

The negative binomial is often somewhat similar to the Poisson (the Poisson is indeed a special case), but has a larger variance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

* (though even so it would be good to have more details, because details will often tend to suggest which distributions to consider)

Comment: I made an edit to suggest a possibility.